# Get Indian Time only in HH:MM hours & mins

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using following code to get local(IST) time. But I don't want to display Date & seconds and also want it in 12hr (AM / PM) format. Please help.

With following code I am getting time like this

> 9/13/2016 11:38:17 AM

I want it like this

> 11:38 AM

```
partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DateTime UTCTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime IndianTime = UTCTime.AddHours(5.5);
    private void Default3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTime.Text = IndianTime;
    }
    public Default3()
    {
        Load += Default3_Load;
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically, you want a custom date/time format? That has nothing to do with the time zone really... see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `myTime.Text = IndianTime.ToString("t");` gives you exactly what you need. As @JonSkeet mentioned, its just about date formatting. This will help you for other kinds of formatting: [DateTime.ToString Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can display your datetime like this

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("6/22/2009 07:00:00 AM");

dt.ToString("HH:mm"); // 07:00 // 24 hour clock // hour is always 2 digits
dt.ToString("hh:mm tt"); // 07:00 AM // 12 hour clock // hour is always 2 digits
dt.ToString("H:mm"); // 7:00 // 24 hour clock
dt.ToString("h:mm tt"); // 7:00 AM // 12 hour clock
```

Comment: Thanks. If I don't want to display Seconds in my time then what should I do? I tried your solution but in that I am getting time Like this (09:30:00 AM) I want only this (09:30 AM)

Answer (score 0):

To get time in India in request format, you can use this

```
var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
var timeInIndia = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, zone);
var timeInIndiaAsString = timeInIndia.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    UTCTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
    IndianTime = UTCTime.AddHours(5.5).Date;
    private void Default3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myTime.Text = IndianTime.ToShortDateString();
    }
    public Default3()
    {
        Load += Default3_Load;
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work, try something like:

```
 DateTime UTCTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime IndianTime = UTCTime.AddHours(5.5).Date;
    partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private void Default3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UTCTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
            DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            IndianTime = epoch.AddDays(Math.Floor(IndianTime.Subtract(epoch).TotalDays));
             myTime.Text = IndianTime.ToShortDateString();
        }
        public Default3()
        {
            Load += Default3_Load;
        }
    }
```

The second example is overkill in terms of formatting, but useful if you need to compare a DateTime to something stored as a Date (as in a database). The result of IndianTime in the second example will evaluate to "true" if you need to "remove the time for a DateTime."

Remember - a DateTime is nothing but an integer - it's up to you to format it however you want.

Comment: What makes you think the OP wants a short date string? That code wouldn't even compile, as you can't convert a *number* into a short date string. There's no benefit here in remembering that a `DateTime` is nothing but an integer...

Comment: Jon - indianTime is a DateTime. DateTime.ToShortDateString will absolutely compile to a TextBox.Text. My point was that a DateTime is stored as an integer struct. The DateTime type is an integer (long to be specific).

Comment: What makes you think you're trying to call it on a `DateTime`, in your second sample? `indianTime` (undeclared) will be of type `double`. And your point about it being an integer is irrelevant, IMO. (For example, in Noda Time the same information is stored very differently, but that doesn't affect how you format it.)

Comment: The second example is for the interior of the prevous example.. Didn't see the need in repeating it, but...

Comment: Well it wouldn't compile, as `Math.Floor` isn't going to return a `DateTime`, is it? (If you meant `IndianTime` instead of `indianTime`, that's another issue.) Fundamentally though, you don't seem to have read the question - the OP doesn't want just a date. They don't want the date at all. They want the time, in a specific format.

Comment: Yes, it will, because you're asking for an Subtract, not a DateTime. DateTime.AddDays(INTEGER) works fine.

Comment: IndianTime = Math.Floor(indianTime.Subtract(epoch).TotalDays); evaluates to midnight on the date in question - thereby "removing" the hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: Nope, `Math.Floor` results in a `double`, not a `DateTime`. The result will be a *number* of days, not a `DateTime`. I give up at this stage - you've ignored a) everything I've said about why this won't compile; b) what the OP is asking for. (Hint: read the question again. What makes you think they're trying to remove hours/minutes/second?)

Comment: Heh-heh - we're both right - I had the Math.Floor in the wrong place.

Comment: No, we're not "both right". It simply wouldn't compile - and still won't as there's no `DateTime.Subtract` method with two parameters (and you're using `TotalDays` as if it's a declared variable somewhere, which it isn't...). What you are doing is pointless anyway because you're *still* completely ignoring what the question is actually asking for. I strongly urge you to delete this answer, as it can only serve to confuse the OP in its current form.

Comment: Yeah - bad syntax. I was caught up on the can't add integer to date thing. My bad. Edit works.

Comment: Right. This code will now compile, but *still* doesn't answer the question. You've been so hung up on getting "the number of days since the Unix epoch" (why not just use the `Date` property, to get midnight?) that you've ignored what the OP is asking for, despite me explaining to you five times that they're trying to format a time.